# Vega-Lite (Deneb for PowerBI) - How to change the starting point of the Y-Axis?

Tags: powerbi, visualization, powerbi-desktop, vega-lite, deneb

By default, the starting point of the Y-Axis is 0. Normally this is fine, but I'd like Y-axis to start from the lowest value. How would I go about resolving this?

Thank you kindly in advance

[image]

[Line-Chart with Y-axis at zero](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtR3k.png)

I've tried viewing the documentation, but I can't quite figure it out. Adjusting "scale"? I'm not too sure. This solution would need to be dynamic so the Y-axis starting point changes depending on the first value in the axis.

EDIT: Thanks to David Bacci for resolving the requestion.
Hovering over the "scale" object, Vega-Lite Online Editor add some documented contxt:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set zero to false. e.g.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "Line chart with conditional axis ticks, labels, and grid.",
  "data": {"url": "data/stocks.csv"},
  "transform": [
    {"filter": "datum.symbol==='GOOG'"},
    {"filter": {"field": "date", "timeUnit": "year", "range": [2006, 2007]}}
  ],
  "width": 400,
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "date",
      "type": "temporal",
      "axis": {
        "tickCount": 8,
        "labelAlign": "left",
        "labelExpr": "[timeFormat(datum.value, '%b'), timeFormat(datum.value, '%m') == '01' ? timeFormat(datum.value, '%Y') : '']",
        "labelOffset": 4,
        "labelPadding": -24,
        "tickSize": 30,
        "gridDash": {
          "condition": {
            "test": {"field": "value", "timeUnit": "month", "equal": 1},
            "value": []
          },
          "value": [2, 2]
        },
        "tickDash": {
          "condition": {
            "test": {"field": "value", "timeUnit": "month", "equal": 1},
            "value": []
          },
          "value": [2, 2]
        }
      }
    },
    "y": {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative",  "scale":{"zero":false},}
  },
  "config": {"axis": {"domainColor": "#ddd", "tickColor": "#ddd"}}
}
```

Comment: outstanding - thank you!. I feel embarrassed now for having not spotted this sooner!

Grazie mille - I'm grateful for your help!

Comment: Absolutely! Marked as solved (i need 4 more points to upvote) :)